# Getting first day of a week with NSDateComponents : changing year

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdatecomponents

Hello
I have a problem with setting a firstWeekDay, here is what I do:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
comp = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:targetDate];
[comp setWeekday:2];

NSDate *firstWeekDay = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
```

If Saturday 2011-01-01 is targetDate, the firstWeekDay in my calendar appears to be Monday 2011-12-26, but in fact it should be Monday 2010-12-26.  How can I make it right?

Comment: Is this possibly the reason why the alarm clock in iOS didn't work properly for some users on 2011-01-01?

Answer (score 35):

To fix this problem, Add **NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit** in the NSDateComponents.

Ex:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate];

[comps setWeekday:2]; // 2: monday
firstDayOfTheWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps setWeekday:7]; // 7: saturday
lastDayOfTheWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: This was solution. If you still have some problem and used NSDayCalendarUnit then try to remove it.

Comment: Why do you need "NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit"? What does it do?

Comment: @Raj, hehe, it actually made your "day" ;-)!

Comment: Indeed, never realized! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// adjust them for first day of previous week (Monday)
[comp setWeekday:2];
[comp setWeek:([comp week] - 1)];
```

Note this solution assumes the first day of the week is Monday.

Comment: Thank you, but your method is not working. firstWeekDay now became 2011-12-20

Answer (score 1):

Below also covers the edge case,

```
- (NSDate *)getFirstDayOfTheWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)givenDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];


   NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:givenDate];
    [components setWeekday:2]; // 1 == Sunday, 7 == Saturday
    if([[calendar dateFromComponents:components] compare: curDate] == NSOrderedDescending) // if start is later in time than end
    {
        [components setWeek:[components week]-1];
    }

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Swift solution (thanks @YvesJusot):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comps = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYearCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnit.WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: NSDate()) as NSDateComponents

comps.setValue(2, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.WeekdayCalendarUnit)
let monday = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)!

println("\(monday)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You suppose to use dynamic values instead of hardcoding 2 as Monday!

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

comps.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday;
firstDayOfTheWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
comps.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday - 1;
lastDayOfTheWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in @JasonGarrett answer and it works for me.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let flags : NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear
let comps = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: NSDate()) as NSDateComponents
                comps.setValue(2, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday)
let monday = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make these two methods as categories to NSDate
// Use This to get First date of the week (Monday)

- (NSDate *) getFirstDayOfWeek {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *compOfDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate:self];

    NSInteger numOfDaysToAdd = compOfDate.weekday == 1 ? -6 : (2 - compOfDate.weekday);

    NSDateComponents *compToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    compToAdd.day = numOfDaysToAdd;

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compToAdd toDate:self options:0];
}

// Use This to get last date of the week (Sunday)

- (NSDate *)getLastDayOfWeek {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *compOfDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate:self];

    NSInteger numOfDaysToAdd = compOfDate.weekday == 1 ? 0 : (8 - compOfDate.weekday);

    NSDateComponents *compToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    compToAdd.day = numOfDaysToAdd;

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compToAdd toDate:self options:0];
}
```